# Tomcat v7.0 is not working during the start (A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, pom.xml

there!

I am having a problem with Tomcat 7x when trying to load a JSP Maven Project: Starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost - Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

I changed many times the version of the dependencies and nothing changes. My JDK is the 1.8 and it is setted.

Any ideas?

Follow my log:

```
mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/7.0.104
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          May 7 2020 19:31:18 UTC
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Server version number: 7.0.104.0
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 10
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            10.0
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_251-b08
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\souza\eclipse-workspace\apache-tomcat-7.0.104
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\souza\eclipse-workspace\apache-tomcat-7.0.104
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\souza\eclipse-workspace\apache-tomcat-7.0.104
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\souza\eclipse-workspace\apache-tomcat-7.0.104
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\souza\eclipse-workspace\apache-tomcat-7.0.104\wtpwebapps
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\souza\eclipse-workspace\apache-tomcat-7.0.104\endorsed
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFORMAÇÕES: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_251/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_251/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_251/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin;C:\maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\\bin;C:\maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\souza\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\souza\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2020.1\bin;;C:\Users\souza\AppData\Roaming\npm;;C:\Windows\system32;;.]
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 902 ms
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service [Catalina]
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.104
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
    INFORMAÇÕES: validateJarFile(C:\Users\souza\eclipse-workspace\apache-tomcat-7.0.104\wtpwebapps\datainfo2\WEB-INF\lib\javax.el-3.0.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:55 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
    INFORMAÇÕES: validateJarFile(C:\Users\souza\eclipse-workspace\apache-tomcat-7.0.104\wtpwebapps\datainfo2\WEB-INF\lib\jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.13.Final.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
    INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    GRAVE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/datainfo2]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:804)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/datainfo2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.jandex.AnnotationTarget.asClass()Lorg/jboss/jandex/ClassInfo;
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexDiscoveryStrategy.buildBeanDefiningAnnotationSet(JandexDiscoveryStrategy.java:116)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexDiscoveryStrategy.beforeDiscovery(JandexDiscoveryStrategy.java:83)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.performDiscovery(AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.java:116)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.createDeployment(WeldServletLifecycle.java:302)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:156)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5642)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 6 more

    mai 23, 2020 9:59:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    GRAVE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:284)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1238)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:804)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/datainfo2]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/datainfo2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.jandex.AnnotationTarget.asClass()Lorg/jboss/jandex/ClassInfo;
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexDiscoveryStrategy.buildBeanDefiningAnnotationSet(JandexDiscoveryStrategy.java:116)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexDiscoveryStrategy.beforeDiscovery(JandexDiscoveryStrategy.java:83)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.performDiscovery(AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.java:116)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.createDeployment(WeldServletLifecycle.java:302)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:156)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5642)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 6 more

    mai 23, 2020 9:59:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1238)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:284)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1238)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:804)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1689)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1679)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/datainfo2]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1227)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/datainfo2]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.jandex.AnnotationTarget.asClass()Lorg/jboss/jandex/ClassInfo;
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexDiscoveryStrategy.buildBeanDefiningAnnotationSet(JandexDiscoveryStrategy.java:116)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.jandex.JandexDiscoveryStrategy.beforeDiscovery(JandexDiscoveryStrategy.java:83)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.performDiscovery(AbstractDiscoveryStrategy.java:116)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.createDeployment(WeldServletLifecycle.java:302)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize(WeldServletLifecycle.java:156)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup(EnhancedListener.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5642)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 6 more

    mai 23, 2020 9:59:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFORMAÇÕES: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFORMAÇÕES: Stopping service [Catalina]
    mai 23, 2020 9:59:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFORMAÇÕES: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.datainfo2</groupId>
  <artifactId>datainfo2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>datainfo2</name>
  <description>Sistema de Cadastro de Usuários para seleção da Datainfo</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <weld.version>3.0.4.Final</weld.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0-beta-3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum.vraptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
         </dependency> 

         <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
            <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl104-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
            <artifactId>displaytag-export-poi</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>datainfo2</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <display-name>Sistema de Cadastro de Usuários</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>messages</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

I simply deleted all my repository of Maven dependencies and dowloaded all again.